# Spark 2.1 table loaded from Hive Metastore has null values

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, emr, metastore

I am trying to migrate table definitions from one Hive metastore to another.

The source cluster has:

- Spark 1.6.0
- Hive 1.1.0 (cdh)
- HDFS

The destination cluster is an EMR cluster with:

- Spark 2.1.1
- Hive 2.1.1
- S3

To migrate the tables I did the following:

1. Copy data from HDFS to S3
2. Run `SHOW CREATE TABLE my_table;` in the source cluster
3. Modify the returned create query - change `LOCATION` from the HDFS path to the S3 path
4. Run the modified query on the destination cluster's Hive
5. Run `SELECT * FROM my_table;`. This returns 0 rows (expected)
6. Run `MSCK REPAIR TABLE my_table;`. This passes as expected and registers the partitions in the metastore.
7. Run `SELECT * FROM my_table LIMIT 10;` - 10 lines are returned with correct values
8. On the destination cluster, from Spark that is configured to work with the Hive Metastore, run the following code: `spark.sql("SELECT * FROM my_table limit 10").show()` - This returns null values!

The result returned from the Spark SQL query has all the correct columns, and the correct number of lines, but all the values are null.

To get Spark to correctly load the values, I can add the following properties to the `TBLPROPERTIES` part of the create query:

```
'spark.sql.partitionProvider'='catalog',
'spark.sql.sources.provider'='org.apache.spark.sql.parquet',
'spark.sql.sources.schema.numPartCols'='<partition-count>',
'spark.sql.sources.schema.numParts'='1',
'spark.sql.sources.schema.part.0'='<json-schema as seen by spark>'
'spark.sql.sources.schema.partCol.0'='<partition name 1>',
'spark.sql.sources.schema.partCol.1'='<partition name 2>',
...
```

The other side of this problem is that in the source cluster, Spark reads the table values without any problem and without the extra `TBLPROPERTIES`.

Why is this happening? How can it be fixed?